# AngularJS - IE8 - Passing $index to a function within ng-click always return 0 and is executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I'm experiencing the following issue. consider this code:

```
<div ng-repeat element in elements>
   <input type="text"/><a ng-click="deleteTag(inputArray, $index)" class="redCross">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the link it will delete the input based on the index value. The function will basically delete the element from an existing array, so it receives the array, and the index.

It works perfect across all the browsers except for IE8 and IE7, if I have three items, the function is executed three times and always receives 0 as index value.

Totally stuck with this issue, your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into the issue, I fixed it replacing the anchor with an input button. That worked for me. Seems to be an angularjs bug.

Comment: Regardless of the question, replacing an anchor with an input is not a solution for any problem.

Comment: Ok, waiting for your feedback on how to solve the issue. If there is a potential bug for IE8, and replacing the anchor with an input fixes the issue, that will be a temporary solution or workaround, in fact a solution.